# Hcatalog hive issue

Tags: hive, hcatalog

I am trying to do this `hcatalog` example from the following link:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_19_6.html

I am getting the following exception when I run the job.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/RecognitionException
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2232)

    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)

    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4764)

    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.getOrCreate(HiveClientCache.java:167)

    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.get(HiveClientCache.java:143)

    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveClient(HCatUtil.java:544)

    at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.getInputJobInfo(InitializeInput.java:103)

    at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.setInput(InitializeInput.java:85)

    at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:85)

    at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:54)

    at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:46)

    at com.otsi.hcat.UseHCat.run(UseHCat.java:69)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)

    at com.otsi.hcat.UseHCat.main(UseHCat.java:96)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/RecognitionException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getClass(MetaStoreUtils.java:1378)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:64)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:498)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:476)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:524)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:398)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:357)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4948)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:154)

    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveClientCache.java:246)

    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$4.call(HiveClientCache.java:170)

    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$4.call(HiveClientCache.java:167)

    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4767)

    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)

    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)

    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)

    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)

    ... 19 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.runtime.RecognitionException
```

Before running the `MR job` i executed following **commands**:

> $ export HCAT_HOME=$HIVE_HOME/hcatalog
>
> $ HCATJAR=$HCAT_HOME/share/hcatalog/hcatalog-core-0.11.0.jar
>
> $
>   HCATPIGJAR=$HCAT_HOME/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-pig-adapter-0.13.0.jar
>
> $ export
>   HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HCATJAR:$HCATPIGJAR:$HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-exec- 
>   0.13.0.jar:$HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-metastore-0.13.0.jar:$HIVE_HOME/lib/jdo-api-  3.0.1.jar:$HIVE_HOME/lib/libfb303-0.9.0.jar:$HIVE_HOME/lib/libthrift-  0.9.0.jar:$HIVE_HOME/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar:    $HIVE_HOME/conf:/usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/etc/hadoop/
>
> $ LIBJARS=`echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH | sed -e 's/:/,/g'`
>
> $ export LIBJARS=$LIBJARS,$HIVE_HOME/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar

Answer (score 1):

I'm not running a CDH distribution, however I was able to get this work with the following configuration settings:

```
export HCAT_HOME=/usr/lib/hive-hcatalog
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
HCATJAR=$HCAT_HOME/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.2.1.1.0-385.jar
HCATPIGJAR=$HCAT_HOME/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-pig-adapter-0.13.0.2.1.1.0-385.jar
HIVE_VERSION=0.13.0.2.1.1.0-385
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HCATJAR:$HCATPIGJAR:$HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-exec-$HIVE_VERSION.jar:$HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-metastore-$HIVE_VERSION.jar:$HIVE_HOME/lib/libfb303-0.9.0.jar:$HIVE_HOME/lib/libthrift-0.9.0.jar:$HIVE_HOME/conf:/etc/hadoop/conf
LIBJARS=`echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH | sed -e 's/:/,/g'`
export LIBJARS=$LIBJARS,$HIVE_HOME/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
```

A few things to note:

1. The comma on the last line between "$LIBJARS" and "$HIVE_HOME" is correct.
2. I removed references to $HIVE_HOME/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar and $HIVE_HOME/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar since I didn't have those in my Hadoop distro.  The code worked fine without it.
3. Hadoop moves pretty quickly so jar versions change.  For each referenced jar file in these settings perform an `ls -l` command to ensure that the jar file actually exists where you believe it should be.
4. This code uses some deprecated API calls.  My suggestion is (at least for now) not to change the code.  I have found that trying to change the code to use the non-deprecated versions breaks the code (see also [Radek's update to the same effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558943/writing-to-hive-from-mapreduce-initialize-hcatoutputformat)).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,I have tried the above solution but still getting the same exception. I have already placed antlr-runtime-3.4.jar in the buildpath and also exported in libjars as above.

Comment: Hi...still i am getting the same exception when i tried the above solution.but when i replaced the colon with comma i am getting different exception.

Comment: Hi...still i am getting the same exception when i tried the above solution.but when i replaced the colon with comma i am getting different exception.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/metadata/HiveStorageHandler

Comment: It looks like you may need to fix your $HADOOP_CLASSPATH.  The class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveStorageHandler is found in $HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-exec[*].jar.  My system has the following softlink that contains the class in question: /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-exec.jar -> hive-exec-0.13.0.2.1.1.0-385.jar.

Comment: I did check the $HADOOP_CLASSPATH..and the jar is in correct path /usr/lib/hive/hive-0.13.0/lib/hive-exec-0.13.0.jar and it contains the required class file org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveStorageHandler ...could not figure out the problem..

Comment: I have edited my answer now that I have gone through the code and configuration and gotten it work work in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following 3 datanucleus jars available on the classpath.

```
datanucleus-rdbms-3.x.x.jar
datanucleus-core-3.x.x.jar
datanucleus-api-jdo-3.x.x.jar
```

Also it is always good to have '$HIVE_HOME/conf' on the HADOOP_CLASSPATH and CLASSPATH because it has important information about how to connect to the metastore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your environment variables in ~./bashrc

```
export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/sqoop
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/Hbase
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export HCAT_HOME=/usr/local/hive/hcatalog
```